# Quantity expressed as the difference of two squares

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

What is the trick you need to use to be able to express the quantity

$(4x^4+8x^3+7x^2+3x+\frac{1}{2})$

as the difference of two squares?

addendum: The answer contains only rational numbers greater than zero.

Comment: Vassilis, please, we've [been](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110669/inscribing-a-cylinder-within-a-sphere#comment311076_110669) [down](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107677/factorizing-complex-numbers) [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105227/more-mysterious-fractions#comment297358_105227) [road](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/105026/69582) [before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A61190+is%3Aq+trick). There is no single "trick" to do things in math - there basically always are multiple ways.

Comment: To @bobble’s point, one “trick” could be (√Q)² - 0² where Q is the original quantity, which I doubt is the intended answer.

Comment: @bobble. I believe there is only one trick. The answer contains only rational numbers greater than zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$$(4x^4+8x^3+7x^2+3x+\frac{1}{2}) = (i^2-j^2)$$

Then

$$(4x^4+8x^3+7x^2+3x+\frac{1}{2}) = (i+j)(i-j)$$

Assuming i and j are polynomials in x of degree no greater than 2, we could say

$$i = ax^2 + bx + c$$
$$j = dx^2 + ex + f$$

Substituting into $(i+j)(i-j)$ and expanding we can then group like terms and compare with the original equation to get the following:

$$a^2-d^2 = 4$$
$$2ab-2ad = 8$$
$$2ac-2df+b^2-e^2 = 7$$
$$2bc-2ef = 3$$
$$c^2-f^2 = \frac{1}{2}$$

i.e. 5 simultaneous equations with 6 unknowns.
Potential solutions include
$$a=2, b=2, c=\frac{3}{4}, d=0, e=0, f=\frac{1}{4}$$
for instance, which gives our two squares as

$$i = 2x^2 + 2x + \frac{3}{4}$$
$$j = \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: One of the squares is $(\frac{1}{4})^2$ if you subtract this from the given quantity then the remaining quantity is a square  as well  $(2x^2+2x+\frac{3}{4})^2$. Now can you explain the four negative votes? This  problem is harder to solve.